# How to make the function of the planes from the lorenz attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, plane-geometry, chaos-theory

How can I make the equation for the planes of the wings of the lorenzattractor, 
I know that the critical point should be used.

But I don't know how I should make this plane, the figure shows in yellow which plane I want.
[image: The plane I wnat]

Answer (score 3):

The "wings" don't lie in a plane; the predominantly blue portion on the right of your image seems to indicate that clearly. You can linearize the system at the unstable fixed points to figure out how the system behaves like a linear system near those points, though. The plane that I suspect you are talking about is somewhat akin to a tangent plane to a surface.

To do this, first define

$$
 \vec{F}(x,y,z) = 
  \left(\begin{matrix}
    u(x,y,z) \\
    v(x,y,z) \\
    w(x,y,z)
\end{matrix}\right)
 =
\left(\begin{matrix}
    \sigma(y-x) \\
    x(\rho-z)-y \\
    xy-\beta z
\end{matrix}\right),
$$
then compute the Jacobian of this function
$$
  \frac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)} = 
  \left(\begin{matrix}
    \partial u/\partial x & \partial u/\partial y & \partial u/\partial z \\
    \partial v/\partial x & \partial v/\partial y & \partial v/\partial z \\
    \partial w/\partial x & \partial w/\partial y & \partial w/\partial z
  \end{matrix}\right)
  =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
 -\sigma & \rho-z & y \\
 \sigma & -1 & x \\
 0 & -x & -\beta \\
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
Next, plug one of the fixed points 
$(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\sqrt{\beta(\rho-1)},\pm\sqrt{\beta(\rho-1)},\rho-1\right)$ and the parameters you're using into the Jacobian. Finally, compute the eigen system of the evaluated Jacobian matrix. If all goes well, one eigenvalue should be real and negative, while the other two should be complex conjugates. The real and imaginary parts of the complex eigenvector should be parallel to the plane of rotation of the *linearized* system. Taking the cross product of those vectors, we can generate the vector shown in the image below:

[image]

I emphasize again, though, that the "wing" of the attractor is *not* contained in a plane.

Comment: So when you use a lineairisation then de eigenvector of the real eigenvalue stands perpendicular to the plane of rotation, but this eigenvector does not stand perpendicular to the plane of rotation in the not-lineairised system? Why don't the wings form a plane?

Comment: Some of the "eigenvector" should be "eigenvalue". It is the left eigenvector to the real eigenvalue that gives a linear form that annihilates the other right eigenvectors. The transpose of that is really perpendicular to their plane. The right eigenvectors/eigenspaces are seldom orthogonal.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann You are right of course. I have edited the post to use the real and imaginary parts of one complex eigenvector.

Comment: @Mari3 No, the real eigenvector is not necessarily perpendicular to the plane of rotation. I have edited my post to reflect the correct approach.

Comment: @Mari3 I'm not sure why you think the wings form a plane - or where you got that idea, as the picture clearly indicates they don't. The point is that *near the fixed point*, the system is well approximated by the linear system. They are not the same system, though, and they are not even close once you move away a bit from the fixed point.

It's a bit like looking at the graph of a function together with a tangent line at a point $x_0$. Near $x_0$, the two are very close but the graph of the function certainly need not be contained in the line.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thanks a lot, now I understand it much better ;)