# What is the angle between the two wings of Lorenz's strange attractor?

Tags: chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

When reading about chaos theory, I am often presented with a picture of a butterfly shape formed by two spirals - Lorenz' strange attractor.

I presume that there is a specific function that generates the most natural example.  If it is a meaningful question, what is the angle between the two planes on which the paths of the spiral, more or less, are located?

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420186/) presents a way to find a vector perpendicular to one of the "wings". One could do that for both wings and then find the angle between the two resulting vectors. Of course, the result will depend upon the parameters chosen in the Lorenz equations. I don't know that there's any most "natural" example.

Comment: Thanks much; very helpful.

Comment: Also, nice write-up!